# Unable to create table in database using Spring Boot and JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, lombok

When I am using my Spring Boot application along with JPA to create a table in my database named schooldb, the code runs fine but I am unable to automatically create a table and have to explicitly create it either using the CMD or any other terminal in an IDE.

Here is my repository class

```
package com.jpabasics.jpaBasics.enitity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Student {

    @Id
     private long studentId;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String emailId;
     private String guardianName;
     private String guardianEmail;
     private String guardianMobile;


}
```

and here is my POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jpabasics</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpaBasics</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jpaBasics</name>
    <description>Jpa basics</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Also here is my application.properties file

```
# Database Config : mysql
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schooldb
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = Lko@6388895330
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# Hibernate Configuration
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Could someone help me out with this please?

Comment: Do you see an error on startup? Did you check the logs to see if the create table statement is being executed or not?

Comment: @greenPadawan The logs show no create table statement, that is why I know that the table is not being created, also there are no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the @table annotation which is required to build a table in your DB to host the entities. Also, it's good custom to annotate your columns as well, to make sure they're named correctly (although in your case, they would've been correctly parsed). For example:

```
package com.jpabasics.jpaBasics.enitity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENTS")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Student {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
     private long studentId;

     @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
     private String firstName;

     @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
     private String lastName;

     @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
     private String emailId;

     @Column(name = "GUARDIAN_NAME")
     private String guardianName;

     @Column(name = "GUARDIAN_EMAIL")
     private String guardianEmail;

     @Column(name = "GUARDIAN_MOBILE")
     private String guardianMobile;

}
```

Comment: I added @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO), then too it worked.
Could you explain the difference if any?

Comment: @DestructiveGamer the generated value annotation helps the JPA to know how to generate the ID automatically - if there is not annotation you’re expected to have unique values or use a DB generator. I always use the annotation because it’s easiest.

Answer (score -1):

I am using same code but still not able to create a table.

Please find below logs

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.1)

```
2023-07-24T13:43:17.936+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] c.e.S.SpringJpaTestApplication           : Starting SpringJpaTestApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 9080 (C:\Users\arpit.verma\Downloads\SpringJPATest\SpringJPATest\target\classes started by arpit.verma in C:\Users\arpit.verma\Downloads\SpringJPATest\SpringJPATest)
2023-07-24T13:43:17.942+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] c.e.S.SpringJpaTestApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-24T13:43:18.890+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-07-24T13:43:18.928+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 18 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-07-24T13:43:19.819+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-07-24T13:43:19.838+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-07-24T13:43:19.839+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.10]
2023-07-24T13:43:20.020+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-07-24T13:43:20.026+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1913 ms
2023-07-24T13:43:20.246+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-24T13:43:20.814+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@c3719e5
2023-07-24T13:43:20.818+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-07-24T13:43:20.877+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-07-24T13:43:20.987+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.5.Final
2023-07-24T13:43:20.992+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-07-24T13:43:21.124+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-07-24T13:43:21.341+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-07-24T13:43:21.602+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-07-24T13:43:21.685+05:30  WARN 9080 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
2023-07-24T13:43:21.810+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-07-24T13:43:22.082+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-07-24T13:43:22.090+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-07-24T13:43:22.154+05:30  WARN 9080 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-07-24T13:43:22.650+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-07-24T13:43:22.666+05:30  INFO 9080 --- [           main] c.e.S.SpringJpaTestApplication           : Started SpringJpaTestApplication in 5.202 seconds (process running for 6.165)
```